# How to open CMD and then pass arguments to CMD using PHP

Tags: php, cmd

I need to create a website that utilized 2 existing encryption CMD.exe in PHP. I know that you can use exec() to open CMD file in PHP, but what if I need to pass some arguments for example the file location to CMD using PHP as well?

Is it possible? Or PHP only allow us to open CMD file only?

Thank you.

Comment: you can send arguments using exec(), you just put them after the file location with a space between them.

Comment: whatever you would type in cmd.exe, you can pass it to exec.